# How much of my root space (19.5GB) should be used up in an installation?

Tags: configuration, cleanup

I have a root partition and a home partition, on a dual boot system (windows)

I currently have 4.9GB available in my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 LTS system after limiting my journal/ folder ([Big /var/log/journal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238214/big-var-log-journal) following the information from Robert Pollak) to 200MB and also clearing out my snapd/ folder from unnecessary snaps.

I'm not certain if only having 4.9 GBs left over is what is expected or whether I should try to find what else is taking up space.

If I run:

```
sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null
```

I get the following:

```
173M    /boot
16K /lost+found
84K /snap
4.0K    /cdrom
4.9G    /var
4.0K    /mnt
968M    /opt
7.4G    /usr
1.5M    /root
16K /media
236K    /tmp
18M /etc
14G /
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: You've not provided any product/release specifics; but Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop & later systems (inc. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop) have a recommended 25GB for the minimum disk allocation; some users (*myself included*) require more than that 25GB minimum, others can do with less (*don't add additional software, don't let upgrades accumulate etc*) but don't forget 25GB was only the recommended minimum.  We all use our systems differently & should accommodate the extra software we'll install in the future, if we *release-upgrade* (this needs free space) or just re-install to upgrade etc.

Comment: You've tagged your question as related to the *root* user?  That directory (`/root/`) is not usually allocated its on directory, is usually on KB or at most MB in size, thus exists on the `/` file-system.  Why did you tag *root* user?  It's disabled by default on a Ubuntu system (*both desktop & server as you didn't specify which you're using*).

Comment: @guiverc sorry fro the late response, I wasn't getting email updates.

Comment: @guiverc (accidentally sent the above comment prematurely)
What do you mean by "product/release specifics"? 
So based on your comment, having only 19.5 GB of space is a mistake on my part and should be increased to at least 25 GB. I'll investigate doing that. 
Could you also provide a link of where 25GB is the minimum root requirement? I can mark that as the solved answer. 

Ah, tagging as Root was, in hindsight, obviously incorrect. I meant to relate it to my root directory. I'll remove the root tag as well. 

I am using Ubuntu Desktop and not server. 
Thank you!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/333796/158442 => https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop =>  "25 GB of free hard drive space"

Comment: If you install a lot of programs, and don't want to ever worry about disk space, reinstall Ubuntu with ~50 GB root partition.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements recommends 25GB for the minimum disk space for / for all releases of Ubuntu Desktop that used GNOME 3 (ie. 17.10 & later). Product & release would be Server|Desktop and release is the *year.month* detail such as 23.04 (2023-April release). Server systems have smaller minimums than Desktops, and for some products the release influences that too.  Root directory is different to the `/root` directory don't forget (the latter being a user directory of the root user). 25GB is minimum; I'm one who adds software thus need 32GB+

Comment: @guiverc I tried to find the minimum Root partition storage requirements with no success, but it appears that the minimum storage requirements implicitly refers to Root. 
Is there a way for me to make your comment marked as the answer?

Comment: As this is a common duplicate question, and is likely to soon be closed as such, do not worry about the answer. The answers will be on the duplicate.