# Trying to run R gave me "Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir' "

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, r, tmp

I checked partition for /tmp and it seems to be full.

```
>> df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       23854928 23579092         0 100% /
```

Checking all the partitions gives this:

```
>> df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs           2021460   1660  2019800    1% /run
/dev/sda2       1525920 398781  1127139   27% /
tmpfs           2021460    461  2020999    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2021460      4  2021456    1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1        0      0        0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sda4      57524224 798172 56726052    2% /home
tmpfs            404292    269   404023    1% /run/user/1000
```

And another command, just for the root directory, gives this

```
>> sudo du -d 1 -h /
17M /etc
835M    /opt
4.0K    /mnt
24G /home
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
2.8M    /run
4.0K    /cdrom
0   /sys
462M    /boot
94M /root
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /srv
232K    /dev
392K    /tmp
9.7G    /var
12G /usr
du: cannot access '/proc/4678/task/4678/fd/46': No such file or directory
du: cannot read directory '/proc/1238545/task/1238545/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/1238545/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access '/proc/1582983/task/1582983/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1582983/task/1582983/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1582983/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1582983/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
203M    /media
14G /snap
60G /
```

I am on Ubuntu 22.04, and can't figure out where and how I need to free up space. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Your `/var` is quite large. You may want to delete some old journals, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238214/big-var-log-journal.

Comment: @Jos that did help, but only removed 5% of my partition space, should I keep deleting files from my partition over time, or is there a long-term solution?

Comment: We can't tell why your `/var` has grown so much, or even if that is unexpected or not, in your system. Now that you've got some air to breathe, find some of the largest directories and files on your partition, and see if they are the symptom of another problem. How to drill down to these problem areas (using tools like `find` and `du`) has come up frequently on this site.